# Best way to copy data from two mysql database

Tags: mysql, copy, migration, database-migration

I have 2 mysql databases in separate servers. Say, DB A and B. Both the database are on centos server.

Say DB A has has 3 tables A1, A2 and A3. We have a web app running which puts data into these tables incrementally. In DB B we have 3 tables, B1, B2 and B3.

We would like the all recurring rows to be copied over to say tables B1, B2 and B3.

One important point to note here is that table structure of A1, A2 and A3 are not same as B1, B2 and B3. Nor that the field names match so simply mysqldump wont probably have.

I have 2 option as per me:

1. Use php script to expose the data as web service in DB server A and consumer it from another script hosted in server.
2. From the said web app running on sever A we connect to database in server B and then it just run insert statement to server B from A.

Any other options if you have then please tell me.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/xa.html

Answer (score 0):

First join the two servers with   [a federated engine](http://winashwin.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/mysql-federated-table/).

Then you can acces the data in both databases.

Comment: Question states, "2 mysql databases in separate servers".